# Why these function runs without binding....?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When a button is clicked `{this.increment}` is invoked. Why `{this.increment}` runs without binding `{this.increment.bind(this)}`

```
export default class App extends Component {
            
              constructor(props) {
                super(props)
                this.state = {
                  count: 0
                }
              }
            
              increment=()=>{
                this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 2 })
              }
        
              render() {
                return (
                  <>
                    <div id='1'>{this.state.count}</div>
                    <button onClick={this.increment}>Increment </button> 
               
                  </>
                )
              }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused about **why binding is required**. It is not required because the function will not be able to run without it. You are passing an event handler to the `onClick` and it will run when button is clicked.

When this piece of code is run : `this.increment`, the `this` is an instance of the class and hence the component. But the **assignment**: `onClick={this.increment}`, does something like the below:

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  speak() {    console.log(`${JSON.stringify(this)}`);
  }
}

let meth = ani.speak;
meth();
```

The context is lost. And `this` becomes `undefined`. So even if increment runs, `this.setState` will throw an error. And that is why binding is required.

In the constructor add this statement:

```
this.increment = this.increment.bind(this)
```

Now your increment is assigned a new function(a new value), where the value of `this` (context) is the class instance.